# Using Firebase, how can I pass a created key to another function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a multiuser app and wanted to use keys to product user information. I created a function that updates the child of a database with a generated key. The following function behaves correctly:

```
unlist(list) {

    var postData = {
      state: "unlisted",
    };

    var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('foods').push().key;

    var updates = {};
    updates['foods' + '/' + list.$key + '/' + 'state' + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);}
```

I have a separate function that works similarly to this:

```
changestate(item) {

    var postData = {
      state: "listed",
    };

    var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('foods').push().key;

    var updates = {};
    updates['foods' + '/' + item.$key + '/' + 'state' + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);}
```

In order to make this work correctly, the key that is created from `unlist(list)` needs to correspond to `var newPostKey` in `changestate(item)` and vice versa. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

cfoster5. What I have understood from your question is that the newPostkey from the unlist function should be passed to the changeState(item) function if that's what you want means you can do that by calling promise in the

```
firebase.database().ref().update(updates).then(function(){
   // You can call changestate function and pass the function  like below
  _changestate(item,newPostkey); 
});
```

and in your changestate function,

```
changestate=function(item,passedkey){
  var newPostKey = passedkey;
}
```

See my [jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/508nc7mf/2/)